# Receives from mapStateToProps the old state, not the new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to the site, and new to React. I would be very happy if someone would help me please.
I built a chat, which allows messages to be sent between users, and everything works great. But there is a problem with the mapStateToProps in my opinion, because when I add a new message, the state itself only changes when I refresh the page. I want it to change immediately, that I will see the conversation in chat immediately and not in the refresh of the page.

This is the code I wrote down, please I would be happy if someone would help me, if I need to add more code I will do it.

Explanation of the code, I have a chat component, where I do mapStateToProps, and use state what redux, I have another chatReducer file, which is responsible for managing the state of the chat, and in fact maybe there is a problem, because I update the state, I do not get it. Only after refreshing the page, I get it.

I have another chatAction file - through which I call chatReducer.

I think the problem is very small, I probably did not enter the correct code in ChatReducer or mapStateToProps, but other than that everything works.

Please I would be happy if anyone would help me, I am new here on the site.

Another thing, the problem is this, I have an array of conversations. It comes from the mapStateToProps, from the state.chat. Once I add a new call through the submitMessage function, I manage to add the message to the database, but the state itself is not updated directly, that's the problem. I want when someone sends a straight message that it will be updated in chat.

chat component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getRealtimeUsers } from '../redux/actions/chatActions';
import { updateMessage } from '../redux/actions/chatActions';
import { getRealtimeConversations } from '../redux/actions/chatActions';


class chat extends Component {
    state = {
        message: '',
        chatStarted: false,
        chatUser: '',
        userUid: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getRealtimeUsers();
    }


    initChat = (user) => {

        this.setState({
            chatStarted: true,
            chatUser: user.handle,
            userUid: user.handle

        });
    }


    submitMessage = (e) => {

        const msgObj = {
            user_uid_1: this.props.user.credentials.handle,
            user_uid_2: this.state.userUid,
            message: this.state.message
        }

        if (this.state.message !== "") {
            this.props.updateMessage(msgObj);
            this.setState({ message: '' });
        }

        console.log(msgObj);

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <section>

                <div>

                    <div>
                        {
                            this.state.chatStarted ?

                                this.props.chat.conversations.map(con =>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{con.message}</p>
                                    </div>)
                                : null
                        }


                    </div>
                    {
                        this.state.chatStarted ?
                            <div>
                                <textarea
                                    value={this.state.message}
                                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
                                    placeholder="Write Message"
                                />
                                <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Send</button>
                            </div> : null
                    }


                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.data,
    chat: state.chat,
    user: state.user
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getRealtimeUsers, updateMessage, getRealtimeConversations }
)(chat);
```

chat reducer

```
import { userConstants } from "../types"

const initialState = {
    users: [],
    conversations: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case `${userConstants.GET_REALTIME_USERS}_REQUEST`:
            return {
                ...state
            }
        case `${userConstants.GET_REALTIME_USERS}_SUCCESS`:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.payload
            }
        case userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES:
            return {
                ...state,
                conversations: action.payload
            }
        case `${userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES}_FAILURE`:
            return {
                ...state,
                conversations: []
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

chat actions

```
import { userConstants } from "../types";
import axios from 'axios';

export const getRealtimeUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: `${userConstants.GET_REALTIME_USERS}_REQUEST` });
    axios
        .get('/realtimeUsers')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({
                type: `${userConstants.GET_REALTIME_USERS}_SUCCESS`,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

export const updateMessage = (msgObj) => (dispatch) => {

    axios.post('/updateMessage', msgObj)
        .then(() => {console.log("message added") })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => (dispatch) => {

    axios.get('/realtimeConversations', 
    {
        params: {
            user: JSON.stringify(user)
        }
      }
    )
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))

}
```

Comment: Rest does not push changes to all clients, a client fetches data and disconnects so if someone else sends a message you only know when you request the data again. You could try socket instead.

Comment: @HMR Thanks for the response, is there any way, that a user knew that another user sent him a message, and would update his state accordingly? I use redux and firebase.

Comment: Firebase gives you live updates through sockets so the answer is [yes](https://css-tricks.com/building-a-real-time-chat-app-with-react-and-firebase/).